# Autodesk AR/VR Toolkit: Will it be further developed in the future

Tags: autodesk-forge

Currently I'm developing a web application to visualize 3D models / dashboarding etc.
To view the model in AR directly on site, I use the Forgetoolkit.
Now Unity introduced their new product 1 week ago: Unity Reflect (available this fall).
If I read this correctly, Reflect basically does the same as Forgetoolkit.

Therefore I would be interested if there are more plans with Forgetoolkit. Will it be further developed in the future?

Forge-Toolkit: http://forgetoolkit.com/#/
Unity-Reflect: https://unity.com/de/aec/reflect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s true that we might review the current capabilities of Forge AR/VR suite at some point with a view to align its functionality with the demands of the developer community so stay tuned to our Forge blog for updates.

However although our toolkit outputs to Unity as the renderer do keep in mind that AR/VR toolkit is meant to enable cloud based AR/VR workflows built/connected with the Forge platform while Unity Reflect interfaces with Revit directly with Revit so these techs don’t really step on the toes of each other in that sense.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.! You are right, AR/VR - Toolkit is meant to enable cloud based AR/VR workflows with the Forge platform. I didnt mention that above.